# Create WebApplicationContext programmatically

Tags: spring

I am trying to setup a test with MockMvc for an existing WebApplication.

In the examples I have seen on the web, the WebApplicationContexts are autowired:

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
```

In my existing tests (for non-web projects) I have created the ApplicationContext programmatically by specifying the location of the XML-file:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Now I would like to create the WebAplicationContext in a similar fashion.
Can I create the WebApplicationContext by programmatically specifying the location of the XML-file and how can this be done?

Comment: I want to do this too. I hate Spring's indiscrete use of annotations and reflection (under the guise of being "declarative") and want to stick to programmatic logic as much as I can.